# How to mount ms-dos(fat) hard disk on mac

Tags: macos

How to mount ms dos fat 32 format harddisk on mac,already try below command but not work:

mkdir /fat_mount
mount -t msdos /dev/diskXXX /fat_mount

please help

Comment: This question belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal:
`diskutil mount /dev/diskxxx`

Comment: Thanks for reply , it show error Volume on disk0s4 failed to mount
If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option, and i have try sudo diskutil mount readOnly /dev/disk0s4 , still not work

Comment: Thanks for reply ,it show an same error : Volume on disk0s4 failed to mount
If the volume is damaged, try the "readOnly" option

Comment: `sudo asr adjust --target /dev/diskxxx --settype "Apple_HFS"`
Run that first, then the previous command.

Comment: it show other error: asr: Volume adjustment failed: Operation not permitted

Comment: Not sure, I can help.